# Sorting files based on a timestamp within the file

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a bunch of files which contain an ascii header with a time stamp **WITHIN** the file, followed by a large chunck of binary data. I would like to list the files sorted by this time stamp, at the command line (bash, etc).

The file headers look similar to the following:

```
encoding: raw
endian: big
dimension: 4
sizes: 128 128 1 4
spacings: 1.0 1.0 1.0 NaN
position: -3164,-13678
date_time: 06.02.12.18:59
user_name: Operator1
sample_name: 
dwell_time: 4.000
count_time: 65.536
duration: 202.000
raster: 79912
pixel_width: 624.3125
pixel_height: 624.3125

....binary data....
```

I would like to sort based on the "date_time" time stamp, which uses the format *dd.mm.yy.hh:mm*

The `sort --key` option looks promising but all my attempts have failed. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question?  If so, in which language are you programming?

Comment: @Paul - Using the command line.

Comment: This question belongs over at the [Super User](http://superuser.com/) SE site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these files are images, so you can use a tool like [`exiftool`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to rename them based on their creation dates, then sort them by name.

If you can't rename them, just dump the names with the creation date to STDOUT and `sort` that, e.g.:

```
exiftool -p '$dateTimeOriginal $filename' -q -f DIRECTORY/WHERE/IMAGES/ARE | sort -n
```

If you only want the filenames in the output, append a `| cut -f 2 -d " "` to the end.

If it's file format which is not recognized by `exiftool` this might or might not work:

```
for f in YOURFILES* ; do
    filedate=`grep --binary-file=text -i -o 'date_time: ...........:..' $f | head -1`
    echo "$filedate $f"
done | sort -n
```

**Note**: this won't work when there are spaces in the filenames (and I'm leaving that to you to resolve). And if you want to output only the sorted filenames, append `| awk '{print $NF}'` after the `sort -n`.

Comment: Thanks, but renaming the files is not an option :(

Comment: Your answer works for most image file formats but this particular file format is proprietary so `exiftool` will not work for me. However the concept is the same, so I can use this approach to achieve the desired result. Thanks.